# Show the existence of random variables satisfying certain conditions (law, independence)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The following question is supposed to be very easy but I cannot think of any good example:
Show the existence of real valued random variables $X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2$ so that the following holds.

1. $P_{X_1}=P_{X_2}, P_{Y_1}=P_{Y_2}$,
2. $P_{X_1+Y_1} = P_{X_2+Y_2}$,
3. $X_2$ and $Y_2$ are independent,
4. $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are not independent.

I tried working with $\Omega=[0,1]^2$ and the lebesgue measure, but it did not work yet.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$, $V$, $W$ be three independent Cauchy distributed random variables. If we set $$X_1 := Y_1 := U\qquad X_2 := V \qquad Y_2 := W,$$ then the properties 1,3,4 are automatically satisfied. Show (e.g. using characteristic functions) that property 2 is also satisfied, i.e. that $$X_1 + Y_1 = 2U$$ has the same distribution as $$X_2+Y_2 = V+W.$$

Comment: Not sure this will be enough to the OP, who now has to find $P_U$ such that the distributions of $2U$ and $U+V$ coincide. Yes it suffices to consider $U$ with $______$ distribution, but...

Comment: @Did Yeah, probably you are right.

Comment: Ok, this might be a solution. But isn't there an easier example that uses more common distributions than the cauchy distribution?

Comment: @user406143 The Cauchy distribution is a pretty common distribution; you can write down explicitly the density as well as the characteristic function. If you are lucky someone else will write another answer to your question and provide a simpler example.

Comment: Cauchy and Dirac are the only solutions, as can be shown by fiddling with the characteristic function of any solution.

Comment: @Did But the Dirac distribution is not a solution for this problem or am I missing something? If both $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are Dirac distributed, they are automatically independent (contradicting property 3).

Comment: Indeed, Dirac distributions solve 2U=U+V in distribution but they are not solutions of the OP's problem because they contradict property 4 (but property 3 is fine). Sorry for the ambiguous previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

This answer draws on the answers to a related question [Is joint normality a necessary condition for the sum of normal random variables to be normal?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/189130/6633) that I asked on stats.SE (and answered too!).

- Let $X_2$ and $Y_2$ denote two independent standard normal random variables. Then, it is well-known that $X_2$ and $Y_2$ are *jointly* normal random variables and that $X_2+Y_2 \sim N(0,2)$.
- Let $X_1$ and $Y_1$ denote two jointly continuous random variables whose joint density has value $2\phi(x)\phi(y)$ on the shaded regions
  shown in the diagram below (borrowed from one of the answers to the question cited above). Here, $\phi(\cdot)$ denotes the standard normal density. Note that $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are *dependent* random variables.

$\hspace{1.5 cm}$[image: ![enter image description here]

Since $\phi(\cdot)$ is an even function of its argument, we have that for $x > 0$, 
\begin{align}
f_{X_1}(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^{-x} 2\phi(x)\phi(y) \,\mathrm dy
+ \int_{0}^{x} 2\phi(x)\phi(y) \,\mathrm dy\\
&=\phi(x)\left[\int_{-\infty}^{-x} 2\phi(y) \,\mathrm dy
+ \int_{0}^{x} 2\phi(y) \,\mathrm dy\right]\\
&=\phi(x)\left[\int_{-\infty}^{-x} \phi(y) \,\mathrm dy
+ \int_{x}^{\infty} \phi(y) \,\mathrm dy
+ \int_{0}^{x} \phi(y) \,\mathrm dy
+ \int_{-x}^{0} \phi(y) \,\mathrm dy\right]\\
&= \phi(x)\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(y) \,\mathrm dy
\right]\\
&= \phi(x)
\end{align}
and similarly for $x < 0$. Thus, $X_1 \sim N(0,1)$ and so is $Y_1\sim N(0,1)$ via similar calculations. Note that $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are *not* jointly
normal random variables. Nonetheless, it is easy to show via the same kinds of calculations exploiting the symmetry of $\phi(\cdot)$ that 
$X_1+Y_1 \sim N(0,2)$.

To summarize,

1. $X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2$ all are standard normal random variables,
2. $X_1+Y_1$ and $X_2+Y_2$ are zero-mean normal random variables with variance $2$,
3. $X_2$ and $Y_2$ are *independent* random variables, and
4. $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are *dependent* random variables